# Why it need so many lcd_enable in command in the lcd_init method?

Tags: pic, lcd

Below are just part of the commands, even with comments, I still couldn't really understand the working principle of LCD even after read it online, is the "lcd_enable()" is the command to write the setting into different registers in the LCD? Also if originally, these commands is not set to the lcd, is there a default setting in the lcd?

```
// PIC16F877A Configuration Bit Settings

// 'C' source line config statements

// CONFIG

#pragma config FOSC = XT    // Oscillator Selection bits (XT oscillator)

#pragma config WDTE = OFF    // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)

#pragma config PWRTE = OFF   // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)

#pragma config BOREN = OFF   // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR disabled)

#pragma config LVP = OFF    // Low-Voltage (Single-Supply) In-Circuit Serial Programming Enable bit (RB3 is digital I/O, HV on MCLR must be used for programming)

#pragma config CPD = OFF    // Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM code protection off)

#pragma config WRT = OFF    // Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits (Write protection off; all program memory may be written to by EECON control)

#pragma config CP = OFF     // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)



// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.

#include <xc.h>



#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000



#define rs RA1

#define rw RA2

#define e RA3

void lcd_init();        //LCD init
void lcd_enable();       //LCD display setting

void lcd_init()

 {

  PORTD=0X01;         //clear screen

  lcd_enable();

  PORTD=0X00;        //8 bits 2 lines 5*7 mode.

  lcd_enable();

  PORTD=0X0F;        //display on,cursor on,blink on.

  lcd_enable();

  PORTD=0X06;        //character not move,cursor rotate right.

  lcd_enable();

  PORTD=0X80;         

  lcd_enable();

 }

void lcd_enable()

 {

  rs=0;           //is command not data

  rw=0;           //is write not read.

  e=0;           //pull low enable signal.

  __delay_ms(100);     //for a while.

  e=1;           //pull high to build the rising edge

 }
```

Comment: Why don't you search in the code for the body of lcd_enable() to see what it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code `lcd_enable()` sends commands to the LCD controller which have previously been set up on its data lines (which are connected to port D). The LCD controller accepts the command when its `enable` pin transitions from high to low. At this time it also checks the `rs` and `rw` pins to see whether a command or data transfer is ordered, and whether data is being written or read.

This `lcd_enable()` function is probably only used to initialize the display, and you are expected to use some other function for writing characters etc. I say this because it has no option to write data or read from the display, and it has a 100 ms delay which is usually only needed during initialization.

For more information on how these controllers work, read the [HD44780 datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf). Note that some 'compatible' controllers have slightly different programming requirements. If your LCD module comes with its own instruction sheet then you should refer to that to verify the correct command sequence for initialization.

Answer (score 1):

I think `lcd_enable()` and actually the hardware pin `E` of the HD44780 is misnamed. Logically, it's the **clock input** of the LCD controller, and I would name it `CLK` or something similar. So, `lcd_enable()` functions doesn't actually *enable* anything, it just generates a rising edge clock signal. The function also resets `R/W` & `RS` so that the value on the data bus is *command write* operation.

HD44780 needs some special initialization procedure after power-up. This is done by specific commands with specific minimum timing requirements. The procedure is well explained on the datasheet.

Comment: The E pin is really named Enable because the LCD controller is intended to connect to MPU with Motorola 6800 type bus interface, which also has pins named E and R/W. So not directly compatible with Intel 8080 type interface with separate RD and WR strobes. And it really is the enable for the bus interface, it is not a clock. For reads the enable starts to drive data to bus. But you are right that the falling enable edge triggers the LCD to maybe advance the address counter to point to next character, so the Enable is a strobe signal.